# JavaScript carousel error - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

So im trying to make a carousel in my website. It consist of a section whose background image will change every 2 seconds with some animations. I have written this javascript code to change the background image of the section but carousel effect is not working.

this is my code :-

```
let index=0;
let imagearr = ["../images/gymbg1.jpg","../images/image1.jpg","../images/image2.jpg","../images/image3.jpg","../images/image4.jpg","../images/image5.jpg"]
function changebackground(){
    let section = document.getElementsByClassName("homepage");
    section.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+imagearr[index]+"')";
    index=index+1;
    if(index>imagearr.length){
        index=0;
        }
    }
setInterval(changebackground,3000);
```

Comment: The error message should tell you what line of code caused it.

Comment: The code you included here compiles just fine. Please add enough related details for us to help you.

Comment: What line does it say the error occurred on? That'll help you identify the syntax error more easily.

Comment: line no 5 . section.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+imagearr[index]+"')";